# Why does this happen with Datagrid?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datagrid, border, datagridtemplatecolumn

I've a Silverlight app (Silverlight 4 in VS2010) wherein I've a datagrid. I wanted to set the border for the datagrid rows. So in the `<DataTemplate>` I wrote this:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"></Border>
```

This worked. Now I wanted to draw border only in the bottom and right and I did this:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black">
  <Border.BorderThickness>
    <Thickness Bottom="1" Left="0" Top="0" Right="1"/>
  </Border.BorderThickness>
</Border>
```

But this throws a XAML parsing error - **Cannot set the read-only property Bottom**

Why would this happen? Is there any alternatives to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" />
```

Comment: I know, it is weird. I found this info here that states that it just does not work like that for some structs in Silverlight (though it works for everything in WPF)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189036(v=vs.95).aspx:

"In certain structures, you cannot use attribute syntax to set the structure's values. Structures where this issue exists include CornerRadius, GridLength, Rect, Size, Thickness and Color. In contrast, Matrix and Point structures can use attributes to set values. (This issue is specific to Silverlight; WPF supports additional XAML forms for structures.)"

Comment: thank you.
i hope here is an explanation to that behaviour [link](http://forums.silverlight.net/post/604714.aspx): "Thickness is a value type and not a class, you can't set its properties in XAML"

Comment: Well, MS says some structs can be set that way, but I guess the general rule for Silverlight is - you can't. I wish they made it more compatible with WPF...